# Warning al compilar Genexus 17 Android

Tags: android, genexus

Al compilar una KB en Genexus 17U10 aparece el siguiente WARNING:

```
WARNING:Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in C:\%DirectorioKB%\CSharpModel\mobile\Android\SDMain\build\outputs\mapping\debug\missing_rules.txt.
WARNING:R8: Missing class org.locationtech.jts.algorithm.CGAlgorithms (referenced from: org.locationtech.spatial4j.shape.Rectangle org.locationtech.spatial4j.shape.jts.JtsShapeFactory.makeRectFromRectangularPoly(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry))
Missing class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate (referenced from: void org.locationtech.spatial4j.io.jts.JtsGeoJSONWriter.write(java.io.Writer, java.text.NumberFormat, org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate) and 14 other contexts)
Missing class org.locationtech.jts.geom.CoordinateSequence (referenced from: void org.locationtech.spatial4j.io.jts.JtsGeoJSONWriter.write(java.io.Writer, java.text.NumberFormat, org.locationtech.jts.geom.CoordinateSequence) and 6 other contexts)
Missing class org.locationtech.jts.geom.CoordinateSequenceFactory (referenced from: org.locationtech.jts.geom.CoordinateSequenceFactory org.locationtech.spatial4j.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory.coordinateSequenceFactory)
Missing class org.locationtech.jts.geom.CoordinateSequenceFilter (referenced from: void org.locationtech.spatial4j.shape.jts.JtsGeometry.shiftGeomByX(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry, int) and 1 other context)
Missing class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Envelope (referenced from: void org.locationtech.spatial4j.shape.jts.JtsGeometry.<init>(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry, org.locationtech.spatial4j.context.jts.JtsSpatialContext, boolean, boolean) and 5 other contexts)
```

¿Cómo lo podría solucionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese es un warning de compilación porque no encuentra clases de soporte de tipos de datos geográficos.

Si usa esos tipos de datos, poner la propiedad "[Use Geography Data Type](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?47557,Use%20Geography%20Data%20Types%20property)" en true. Sino usa los tipos de datos geograficos pueden ignorar el warning.

Comment: Excelente! gracias fpanizza por la solución y aclaración.